# How to initialize an array of type another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to initialise values to the children array in Rootobject but it gave me error.
- I tried t make an object of class Child but it did not work either, I just need to know how to set values to the array of type another class which contains other values. Your help would be appreciated.

```
public class Rootobject{

   public Child[] children { get; set; }
   public Data data { get; set; }
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Data{
   //  public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Child{
   public Child1[] children { get; set; }
   public Data1 data { get; set; }
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Data1{

public int playcount { get; set; }
public int area { get; set; }
}

public class Child1{

public object[] children { get; set; }
public Data2 data { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Data2{

public string playcount { get; set; }
public string color { get; set; }
public string image { get; set; }
public int area { get; set; }
}
```

this is where I initialise the values (what should i write in children):

```
var RegisteredUsers = new List<Rootobject>();
RegisteredUsers.Add(new Rootobject() { children = { }, data = { }, 
                                       id = "102", name = "zaki" });
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `java` ?

Comment: Anytime you say "it gave me an error" you should always tell us what the error is.

Comment: not clear what is Child1[] and    Data1  how do you declare them and where. Can you post declaration? When I replace it in the code on Child[] and Data it is all working

Comment: @Yuri done.. check it

Comment: This code should work. What line generates an error?

Comment: thank u, i did it :) and it works fine now, but i have a problem now, i am trying to send a variable to javascript through aspx.cs file using this line in javascript but it does not work var json = "<%=serializedResult%>";

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hand in an array just create one of type Child.

```
Child[] children = new Child[10];
//Then initialize each element.
```

In your Child class it looks like your expecting type Child1 which is not the same as Child. That will most likely cause the error.

Also I'm not sure why you tagged this question with java.

Comment: sorry i tagged it by mistake.. i have an array of type another class and i want to put some values in this array but i do not know how because its type is Child

Comment: If the class Child1 exists then just use an array as shown above. And use Child1 instead of Child. You should take lists in conciderations. Then you can pass in the children = { //Name of Array goes here }

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have uninitialized arrays in your code.

To make it work change arrays to List

```
public List<Child>children { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `Child1` does not exist in the context of your application. Search for it, and rename it to `Child`.

Comment: I copied your code but changed Child1 to Child and Data1 to Data and all worked fine. Could you show the code for Child1 and Data1?

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly looking, but if you really want...

```
var RegisteredUsers = new List<Rootobject>();
RegisteredUsers.Add(new Rootobject()
{
    children = new Child[] {
        new Child { id= "1", name="Ivan"},
        new Child { id= "2", name="Vladimir"}
    },
    data = { },
    id = "102",
    name = "zaki"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using LinqPad, you can copy/paste this code there and will see that it is working

```
var RegisteredUsers = new List<Rootobject>();
RegisteredUsers.Add(new Rootobject() { children = { }, data = { }, 
                                   id = "102", name = "zaki" });
        RegisteredUsers.Dump();                        



                                   }


public class Rootobject{

public Child[] children { get; set; }
public Data data { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Data{
   //  public string name { get; set; }
 }
public class Child{
  public Child1[] children { get; set; }
   public Data1 data { get; set; }
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Data1{

public int playcount { get; set; }
public int area { get; set; }
}

public class Child1{

  public object[] children { get; set; }
  public Data2 data { get; set; }
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}
```

public class Data2{

```
 public string playcount { get; set; }
 public string color { get; set; }
 public string image { get; set; }
 public int area { get; set; }
```